# This code never gets to the point of saving the record, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to check preexistence before storing.  Using promises never reaches the point of saving a new record, but it tells me when it is duplicated...

What am I doing wrong?

```
create: (person) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {autoIndex: false})
    .then(
      () => {
        // Checking preexistence
        module.exports.readByEmail(person.email)
        .then((personFound)=>{
          if(personFound){
            reject("Person already exists.");
          }else{
            // Saving
            Person.create(person, (err, storedPerson) => {
              if(err) reject(err);
              resolve(storedPerson);
              mongoose.connection.close();
            });
          }
        });
      },
      err => {reject(err);}
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: what's in your `readByEmail` function? seems like you're ignoring any errors on the result of that query

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up `Person` as a valid mongoose Model?

```
let Person = mongoose.model(...);
```

I'd try

```
let newPerson = new Person(person);
newPerson
  .save()
  .then(storedPerson => resolve(storedPerson))
  .catch(err => reject(err));
```

Comment: Everything worked fine, before checking unique key... I Do have a correct model for Person... :(

Comment: Does it even come to the point, where the Person creation starts?
Have you tried this? What happens, when there is no duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

See if this will work for you:

```
create: (person) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {autoIndex: false})
    .then(() => 
        // Checking preexistence
        module.exports.readByEmail(person.email)
        .then((personFound)=>{
          if(personFound){
            reject("Person already exists.");
          } else {
            // Saving
            return Person.create(person, (err, storedPerson) => {
              if(err) reject(err);
              resolve(storedPerson);
              mongoose.connection.close();
            });
          }
        }),
      err => reject(err)
    );
  });
}
```

I added implicit returns and one explicit for the `Person.create`.